# Vue navigate from child route to parent of parent route not working

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I have a route structure like this:

```
routes: [
  {
     path: '/login', 
     name: 'Login', 
     component: Login
  },
  {
     path: '/', 
     component: Index, 
     redirect: '/riders', 
     children: [
        { 
           path: 'users', 
           name: 'Users', 
           component: Users
        },
        {
           path: 'owners', 
           name: 'Owners', 
           component: Owners
        },
        {  
           path: 'writers', 
           component: Writers, 
           redirect: '/junior', 
           children: [
              {
                 path: 'junior', 
                 name: 'Junior', 
                 component: JuniorWriters
              },
              {  
                 path: 'senior', 
                 name: 'Senior', 
                 component: SeniorWriters
              }
           ]
        } 
     ] 
  }
]
```

My `Users`, `Owners` and `Writers` are accessible through a navbar that is in the index component and their components are rendered in the  section of the Index component.

In the Writers component I have another  where `junior` and `senior` are nested. Links to load the `JuniorWriters` and `SeniorWriters` components are accessible in the Writers component.

However, since my navtab is in the index component which is the overall parent, it is accessible in all components.

When I navigate to ***/writers/junior (or senior)*** the correct component loads, however, if I select owners or users from the nav tabs, **the path changes** to ***/writers/junior/owners*** (or users).

**Question:**

How can I implement this such that the route would be ***/users*** or ***/owners*** anytime they are selected from the nav tab, regardless of what the path is when they are selected?

Comment: hope its a typo and `riders` is actually `writers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by using the name instead of the path in the :to i.e :to="{name: item.index}"

Answer (score 2):

Path is changing to `/writers/junior/owners` when you load `/users` or `/owners`,
because you have added `redirect:'writers'` field in parent which basically [redirects](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#redirect) to writers and writers also has a `redirect:junior` field so it redirects to writers/junior and then appends owners , so final path is becoming `writers/junior/owners`.

You can try something like this, 
  Giving `path:'/users'` instead of `path:'users'`

```
  routes: [
  {
     path: '/login', 
     name: 'Login', 
     component: Login
  },
  {
     path: '/', 
     component: Index, 
     children: [
        { 
           path: '/users', 
           name: 'Users', 
           component: Users
        },
        {
           path: '/owners', 
           name: 'Owners', 
           component: Owners
        },
        {  
           path: '/writers', 
           component: Writers, 
           children: [
              {
                 path: 'junior', 
                 name: 'Junior', 
                 component: JuniorWriters
              },
              {  
                 path: 'senior', 
                 name: 'Senior', 
                 component: SeniorWriters
              }
           ]
        } 
     ] 
  }
]
```

Comment: tried that, didn't change anything though, navigating from say /writers/junior to say users still results in a path like /writers/junior/users

Comment: Did you remove `redirect:` as well?

Comment: Can you add your navtab code to the question. Issue might be in it.

Comment: `<md-button class="bar-item md-icon-button" v-for="(item, index) in sideBarActions" :key="index" :to="item.key">`

Comment: i'm using vue material, the item.key is identical to the path in the routes file for each item in the navbar (users, owners, writers)

Comment: You may try router-link for the routing, `<router-link class="bar-item md-icon-button" :to="item.key">
      //your text
    </router-link>`
https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to

Comment: i fixed it by using the name instead of the path in the :to i.e :to="{name: item.index}"

Comment: You should put it as answer